# How can I create 'regular' typology from a skin modifier after applying it?

Tags: modifiers, edit-mode

I am trying to make a hand. Started off with a skin modifier and worked from there.
For some reason, the typology is all messed up after applying the modifier.
The geometry looks like the second picture. You can mostly see it at the base of each finger, but also on top of the hand. I cannot really work with this.
Something like the geometry shown in the third picture already be something I can work with I feel like.

I tried moving the vertices around and scaling them, but nothing seems to matter. How can I get regular planes to work with after applying the skin modifier?

Thank!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, what do you mean when you say that you can't get the regular planes? Maybe show the topology. Also the topology is not very good in picture 3

Comment: I have added a new second picture. That is what the typology looks like for me.

Comment: Ok so you need to add some edge loops with the knife, dissolve other edge loops, etc

Comment: The resulting geometry here will highly depend on vertices radii.

Comment: @moonboots so the only solution would be manually trying to creating typology that you might like?

Comment: @lemon so how would I be able to change those? Do I need to change those radii?

Comment: @DPlayground, skin modifier is not really designed for modelling... i've no clue about that.

Comment: I'm not sure that using the Skin modifier is a good method for this object because the topology will always be messed up, were you inspired by a tutorial?

Comment: I was indeed inspired by a tutorial. But you would use a skin modifier to make arm and legs right? So what would you do to create a hand, just extrude different faces and move them to your liking? I would like to use a rig to move the arm, hand and fingers at some point.

Comment: It's ok to model arms and legs but it gets complicated for the hand as you see, it will need a lot of topology corrections, so at one point maybe it's easier to work with classic 3D modeling (extrusions)